# How to avoid long if chain with similar content

Tags: r, if-statement, design-patterns, matching

I'm currently writing an R function `get_line_type(line)` to output the *type* of a line (a string). For every currently possible type there is a function of the form `is_TYPENAME_line(line)` which returns a boolean value indicating whether the line is of this specific type. Chaining these `is_TYPENAME_line` functions together creates the `get_line_type(line)` function and currently looks like this

```
is_fish_line <- function(line) {
  return (any(grep("fish", line)))
}

is_mouse_line <- function(line) {
  return (any(grep("mouse", line)))
}

get_line_type <- function(line) {
  identified_types <- character(0)

  if(is_fish_line(line)) { identified_types[length(identified_types) + 1] <- "FISH" }
  if(is_mouse_line(line)) { identified_types[length(identified_types) + 1] <- "MOUSE" }

  if (length(identified_types) > 1) {
    stop("Matched multiple types: ", paste(identified_types, collapse = ", "), "\t", "Line: ", line)
  }

  return(if(length(identified_types) == 1) identified_types[1] else "UNKOWN")
}
```

This code works like this

> ```
> > get_line_type("The fish seems happy.")
> [1] "FISH"
> > get_line_type("A mouse is living in this house.")
> [1] "MOUSE"
> > get_line_type("The tiger is the king of the jungle.")
> [1] "UNKOWN"
> > get_line_type("The fish and the mouse are friends.")
> Error in get_line_type("The fish and the mouse are friends.") : 
>   Matched multiple types: FISH, MOUSE Line: The fish and the mouse are friends.
> ```

Inside the function a list `identified_types` with the names of all the identified types for the argument line is created. If no type was found `UNKOWN` is returned. If exactly one type was identified the identified type is returned. If more than one type was identified an error occurs (this should not happen).

In the future the list of possible types may grow and I can just add another `if`-statement into the chain to make this work, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant approach to this, since each conditional looks so similar.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a dummy dataset? A possible solution is `case_when()` in the dplyr package.

Comment: @shortessay What do you mean with  _dummy dataset_? Should I post all the functions `is_age_question`, `is_product_search_line`, `is_tax_message_line`, `...`?

Comment: A small example of your data (with the same column names, rows mirroring your data's real rows, etc.). Please see [reprex do's and don't](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/reprex-dos-and-donts.html) here. It makes it easier to make sure our answers are answering your questions. Hope that is helpful!

Comment: @shortessay I replaced the code with a shorter complete version as well as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but here is something to consider:

Create a vector containing the "TYPENAMES" that you include in your functions. You then can dynamically build these functions and place in a named list called `funcList`.

Your `get_line_type` function can call all the functions and providing `line` as the argument. The results can be simplified easily, as you return `TRUE` or `FALSE` from these functions.

I noticed in the comment you might having two words with a space (e.g., "product search"). In `all_types` you would need to put an underscore between those words to create a usable function without spaces. In addition, the `identified_types` could be modified to remove underscores if needed.

```
all_types <- c("fish", "mouse")
funcList <- lapply(all_types, function(x) eval(parse(text = paste0('is_', x, '_line'))))
names(funcList) <- all_types

get_line_type <- function(line) {
  lst <- lapply(funcList, do.call, list(line))
  identified_types <- names(lst[unlist(lst)])
  if (length(identified_types) > 1) {
    stop("Matched multiple types: ", paste(identified_types, collapse = ", "), "\t", "Line: ", line)
  }
  return(if(length(identified_types) == 1) identified_types[1] else "UNKNOWN")
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks better than an endless block of `if`'s. Is there any reason to put the variables `all_types` and `funcList` _outside_ of the function definition? I'm wiring a package. Will this export these variables as well?

Comment: Feel free to put everything inside your function for your package. There are options to have data objects and use internal data but it sounds like you don't need it.

Comment: Perfect. I edited your code a little bit (to not build the functions) and used a list with the tokens as names and the functions as content. It now looks like [this](https://pastebin.com/zAWg6k5P).

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake.